# I want to access record of null in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

In my `crossing_cash_memo` table in column `due_to` and value is `consignee`,`cash` and other is Null.I want hide `cash` data and show remaining data but my null data is not shows.

[image]

I am trying like this:

```
  public function fetchDue($rec_type){
  $query = $this->db->select('user.user_full_name as consignor,user1.user_full_name as consignee,c.*')
         ->from('crossing_cash_memo c')

         ->join('ts_users user', 'c.consignor_name=user.user_id')
         ->join('ts_users user1', 'c.consignee_name=user1.user_id')

         ->where('c.memo_status','cash_memo')
         ->where_not_in('c.due_to','cash') 
         ->order_by('c.lr_no','asc')
         ->get();                            
         return $query->result();
  }
```

How I can show `NULL` record in where condition

Comment: try `->where_not_in('c.due_to',['cash']) `

Comment: try where('c.due_to' !=,'cash');

Comment: @Jack still I am not shows my `null` records it only hide `cash` records I want to show all remaining records.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra as per image `4,7` is `NULL` I want to show null records also.

Comment: @farhantechno `->where_not_in('c.due_to',['cash'])` will exclude only `cash` and show all other record. `null` not getting because of join may be, show your entire `table` structure

Comment: you can try in another type of raw query without using this line by line

Comment: @Jack can you post raw query for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this method,I don't table name correctly you change it as yours

```
 $query =$this->db->query("SELECT * from crossing_cash_memo Left outer join ts_users on `ts_users`.`user_id` = `crossing_cash_memo`.`consignor_name` left outer join ts_users on `ts_users`.`user_id`= crossing_cash_memo.consignee_name where memo_status = 'cash_memo' and where due_to != 'cash' order by lr_no ASC")->result_array();
 }
```

Comment: in function you have mentioned $rec_type this where you using in query?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
    public function fetchDue($rec_type){
       $query = $this->db->select('user.user_full_name as consignor,user1.user_full_name as consignee,c.*')
     ->from('crossing_cash_memo c')

     ->join('ts_users user', 'c.consignor_name=user.user_id', 'left')
     ->join('ts_users user1', 'c.consignee_name=user1.user_id', 'left')

     ->where(array('c.memo_status' => 'cash_memo', 'c.due_to !=' =>'cash'))
     ->order_by('c.lr_no','asc')
     ->get();                            
     return $query->result();
  }
```